# SFML is not rendering 8-bit bitmaps properly

Tags: c#, bitmap, rendering, sfml

Using SFML, I can render about any picture format using the following code:

```
        SFML.Graphics.Image     img = new SFML.Graphics.Image("pic.bmp");
        SFML.Graphics.Texture   tex = new Texture(img);
        SFML.Graphics.Sprite    sprite = new Sprite(tex);
        renderWindow.Draw(sprite);
```

But this is not working correctly with a few bitmaps (files with .bmp extension) which are formatted in 8 bits (256 colors). It looks like the SFML lib is attempting to read it in 16 or 32 bits.

[image: On the left is the original picture, on the right the one that failed to render.]

Is there something to fix this situation?

---

**Update:** I have opened problematic bmp files with paint and just saved them in the same format (8bits), then SFML became able to display those properly. But this is only a test and I can't do it using paint, I need a code-only solution.

Comment: What version of SFML.NET are you using? We're using stb_image to load images. According to the documentation it supports "BMP non-1bpp, non-RLE".

Comment: I am using SFML 2.4.0, the installed nuget package is called "Graphnode.SFML.Net", it is a "Fork of SFML.Net 2.4 that includes both x86 and x64 versions of CSFML" created by Laurent Gomila and Zachariah Brown.

Comment: We recently released the first official set of NuGet packages for SFML.Net, which are based on SFML 2.5. Might want to give those a try, but I guess it won't help you with the issue at hand: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SFML.Net/

Answer (score 0):

If resaving the files again in a different application fixes the issue, then this sounds to me like you have a special format that's not supported by [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) and thus isn't supported by SFML.

I highly recommend to use the PNG format, as it supports proper transparency and uses a loss-less compression.